# so what mics are these?

Tags: microphone, dark, knight, recordist

What mics are these fine sound recordists using and why?

[image]

Comment: can't really get a good look at 'em. is there a link to a larger version?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hcd22.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Sennheiser MKH50 i'd say, from the looks of the suspension and size, the mic body also seems to widen close to the capsule.

Because they sound great in interiors and at that distance

Comment: That's what they look like to me as well... be my guess.

Comment: MKH50 is exactly what I was thinking as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to go with Utopia on this one... if you zoom in on the hi-res link Ed sent, you can definitely see the familiar body shape of the MKH50... at least on the far mic. On a completely unrelated note - that boom op in the shot could be my twin! :)

Comment: haha your twin :D ;) We don't have mkh50's at work I don't think (but I'm surprised by what I find laying around) but we have some AKG 300 with CK91's, might try out rather than the usual 416 for a bit of variation/test. 

Comment: I'd certainly give them a try - I've used an AKG 451/CK1 on several indie features - it's become my goto on interiors. 416's and the like (long shotguns) can be problematic when there are lots of early reflections -i.e a room with lots of hard surfaces, like the one in the shot- hence the use of Mk41's and MKH50's

Comment: And he seriously DOES look like me... even my wife thinks it's uncanny! :)